# Angular Filter Datasource By Interface

Tags: angular, filter

if got a Angular Material Datatable and i like to filter it by multiple Input fields.
If transfer everything to a Interface and passed this variable.

Now the question, is there any good option to filter the datasource by these Interface?

```js
export interface IAZEFilter {
    fiSearch?: string;
    fiZeitraumVon?: string;
    fiZeitraumBis?: string;
    fiBuchungsart?: number[];
    fiStatus?: number[];
}
```

Comment: What kind of DataSource do you have? Do you want to filter the items client-side or server-side? Can you clarify a bit more? You left a bit too much to guess.

Comment: Sorry, my Datasource is from an Api, passed to ne MatTableDataSource. I like to filter the Data client site.